# IIS 8.5 "Service Unavailable" instead of throwing an error

Tags: .net, sql-server-2014, iis-8.5

I wonder if someone can help me with this. (Apologies, this might be TL;DR for some..)

We've recently migrated our C# MVC website from one server to another similar spec cloud server (first one is 2 vCPU 4GB 64 bit WS2012 IIS 8, the new one is 4 vCPU 4GB 64 bit WS2012 R2 IIS 8.5).

Having gone through the initial hurdles of setting up MVC, rewrite module, etc. we successfully set up the new system - apart from one little issue. There are some longer-running reports as stored procedures in the system that normally run for about 5 minutes. Previously we had to increase script- and commandTimeouts for these so that they don't throw the usual "connection timed out" exception.
We checked again, and these reports still run flawlessly on the old servers. 
However, on the new server, the same reports started throwing a 'Service Unavailable' error on execution which actually kills the site for a few minutes unless we restart the site and recycle the app pool (based on the appcmd command the apppool remains in the 'started' state, but all the other sections of the website come up with the same 'Service Unavailable' error).

[image]

So having had a go at this with the hosting provider all we managed to identify is that once the stored procedure is triggered, it runs - and probably finishes - in the background, but the service unavailable message appears after 30 seconds (1 minute 5 seconds in some cases).

Thinking this can be caused by 2 things: resource shortage or the length of process, I mocked up a stored procedure that only executes a 2-minute WAITFOR command. This process results in the same service unavailable.

This for me means the problem is either in IIS or in the code. I then went through all the necessary loops:

- %systemdrive%\windows\system32\logfiles\httperr folder showing Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue on each timeout,
- changed the Rapid Fail Protection to 10 errors in 1 minute
- EventLog doesn't show any warnings or errors connected to this

I then applied try-catch blocks around the erroring bits hoping I could get more information about the issue, but instead of getting any errors, the app pool seems to shut down before the error is emitted.

So my question is: is there a way for me to gain more insight about why this is happening?

But more importantly: is there a way to force the system to throw an error instead of shutting down?

Thanks for the help.
Any more info needed, please let me know.

**UPDATE**

In the meantime, I managed to uncover another important point. Setting up a local website in IIS (as in hooked back to localhost via hosts) that points to the same code and database as the remote URL does - actually works fine. No 'Service Unavailable' error and the execution finishes without a timeout.

I tried switching off the firewall to see if that causes it, but that didn't change a thing. 
I hope this might prompt someone..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it took me about a week, I finally managed to resolve my issue - the last update posted prompted me to have a look outside the server, and voilá!

Unfortunately, when setting up the new server, we were advised by Rackspace to use a load balancer, which, ignoring any timeout extensions simply shut down all traffic to and from the site after the 30 second timeout. Why? I can't tell. I hope there's someone out there who can.

Still investigating how and why this can occur, but I thought I'd just leave this one here instead of deleting the question, just in case someone comes across the same issue - hopefully it might save some wasted hours.

Comment: It would be useful to analyze any error pages (HTTP response messages) to see who in fact sent them. If you had done so, I think you would find that this Service Unavailable page was not sent by IIS, and should have solved it a little bit earlier.

Comment: Hi @LexLi, yes, exactly my thought, but my main issue was that I didn't have any error messages shown or logged on the server and couldn't even force it to throw an exception for me to debug. The only screen I received was the screenshot above - which, as you can imagine led to a 'beat around the bush' week for me.